# WebRequest SOAP con WSS-PasswordType PasswordText

Tags: asp.net-mvc, soap

Necesito hacer un POST a un servicio web y no encuentro la vuelta.

Logré realizar la petición desde la app SoapUI, pero cuando llevo eso mismo al código en C# de ASPNET MVC siempre obtengo el error: "The requested URL was rejected"

Básicamente no se dónde configurar los datos de seguridad (usuario, contraseña y tipo de password, en este caso PASSWORDTEXT).

Tendrán algún ejemplo?

Les dejo lo que tengo armado que logré rescatar de otro ejemplos en la web:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestWSFalabella()
{
    var _url = "url";
    var _action = "";

    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);

    string auth = string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "usuario", "password"))));
    webRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
    webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, auth);


    webRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

    // begin async call to web request.
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

    // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
    // do something usefull here like update your UI.
    asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // get the response from the completed web request.
    string soapResult;
    using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.Write(soapResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

les dejo cómo resolví esto.

El esqueleto de los pasos es este:

```
XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(estadoTCV);
HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(url, action);

InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

string result;
using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Y el problema que tenía lo resolví en el *CreateSoapEnvelope* dónde tuve que agregar un sector específico con los datos de seguridad, dónde puse los [] (corchetes) habría que reemplazar por los datos reales.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand='1' xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' >
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken [usernameToken]' >
    <wsse:Username>[username]</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText' >[password]</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary' >[passwordCodificado]</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2018-12-05T19:05:12.461Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
```

En mi caso todos los tags tenían que esta, de lo contrario fallaba.